# HQL query with column alias and group by

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hql

I'm trying to do a complex query with hibernate and HQL, the query logic works in my mysql database

the mysql query is:

```sql
SELECT GetTaskStatus(t.due_date, t.completed_date) as status, 
       count(*) as total  
FROM tasks t  
GROUP BY status
```

the GetTaskStatus is a function registred in my db schema, it is working and i've another query which uses it in the where clause and the HQL works fine.... but i've tried many stuff and this specific query wont work

```
@Query("SELECT GetTaskStatus(t.dueDate, t.completedDate) as status FROM Task t GROUP BY status")
```

wont work...

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'GetTaskStatus' {originalText=GetTaskStatus}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       +-[DOT] DotNode: 'task0_.due_date' {propertyName=dueDate,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=dueDate,path=t.dueDate,tableAlias=task0_,className=br.com.fisgar.crm.entities.Task,classAlias=t}
       |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'task0_.id' {alias=t, className=br.com.fisgar.crm.entities.Task, tableAlias=task0_}
       |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'dueDate' {originalText=dueDate}
       \-[DOT] DotNode: 'task0_.completed_date' {propertyName=completedDate,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=completedDate,path=t.completedDate,tableAlias=task0_,className=br.com.fisgar.crm.entities.Task,classAlias=t}
          +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'task0_.id' {alias=t, className=br.com.fisgar.crm.entities.Task, tableAlias=task0_}
          \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'completedDate' {originalText=completedDate}
```

another question in same topic, how can I return a raw column value type from a jpa repository so i dont need to create a new type only to hold the result of this query? something like

List<Map<String,Object>>